# Significado: polvorientas palabras

Tags: uso-de-palabras

> "Saboreando con fruición las polvorientas palabras".

[image]

Dudas:

1. Saboreando = do it with pleasure?
2. Con fruición = ¿saboreando? Is it an outdated phrase?
3. Polvorientas palabras: Can't have a clear concept of this phrase.

Comment: You can attach an image by clicking on the square button with the mountains in the upper bar of the body section. It should be the sixth button. I'm not sure, but I don't think you can attach an audio file. For more information click on the question mark in the right side of the same bar and then click on *advanced help*.

Comment: I would add that "polvorientas palabras", in my opinion, has the sense of "old words", as Toulousain says, like objects that exist since long time ago and have accumulated dust over them. This words bring to the memory past times, where the name "Cañón de Fastasmas" was first used.

Answer (score 4):

I would need context here but a translation could be "tasting with delight the dusty words"

"Saboreando" means "tasting". It is used metaphorically here. This metaphor is more common in literature when the words are pronounced (as words would be both tasted and pronounced in the mouth)

"Con fruición" is indeed a bit outdated. It means with delight, with joy, with a sense of self-indulgence.

"Polvorientas palabras" would probably mean "old words" or "words that have not been used recently", or "words that were forgotten". I would need a bit more of context here.